# Elasticsearch: excluding filters while faceting possible? (like in Solr)

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, faceted-search

I'm looking into changing from Solr to ES. 
One of the things I can't find info about is whether ES lets me define exclusion filters when faceting.

For example consider `producttype` with values: `A,B,C` which I want to facet on (i.e: show counts for). Also consider that the query is constrained to `producttype: A`.

In this case Solr allows me to specify that I want to exclude the contraint `producttype: A` from impacting faceting on `producttype`. IOW, it displays counts on `producttype` as if the constraint `producttype: A` has not been applied.

How to do this in Solr see: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters > Tagging and excluding Filters

Is there any way to do this in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can.

While you can use filters within the query DSL, the search API also accepts a top-level `filter` parameter, which is used for filtering the search results AFTER the facets have been calculated.

For example:

1) First, create your index, and because you want `product_type` to be treated as an enum, set it to be `not_analyzed`:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "product" : {
         "properties" : {
            "product_type" : {
               "index" : "not_analyzed",
               "type" : "string"
            },
            "product_name" : {
               "type" : "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

2) Index some docs (note, doc 3 has a different `product_name`):

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/1?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "product_type" : "A",
   "product_name" : "foo bar"
}
'
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/2?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "product_type" : "B",
   "product_name" : "foo bar"
}
'
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/3?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "product_type" : "C",
   "product_name" : "bar"
}
'
```

3) Perform a search for products whose name contains `foo` (which excludes doc 3 and thus `product_type` `C`), calculate facets for `product_type` for all docs which have `foo` in the `product_name`, then filter the search results by `product_type` == `A`:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "text" : {
         "product_name" : "foo"
      }
   },
   "filter" : {
      "term" : {
         "product_type" : "A"
      }
   },
   "facets" : {
      "product_type" : {
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "product_type"
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "product_type" : "A",
#                "product_name" : "foo bar"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.19178301,
#             "_index" : "my_index",
#             "_id" : "1",
#             "_type" : "product"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 0.19178301,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "facets" : {
#       "product_type" : {
#          "other" : 0,
#          "terms" : [
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "B"
#             },
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "A"
#             }
#          ],
#          "missing" : 0,
#          "_type" : "terms",
#          "total" : 2
#       }
#    },
#    "took" : 3
# }
```

4) Perform a search for `foo` in the `product_name`, but calculate facets for all products in the index, by specifying the `global` parameter:

```
# [Wed Jan 18 17:15:09 2012] Protocol: http, Server: 192.168.5.10:9200
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "text" : {
         "product_name" : "foo"
      }
   },
   "filter" : {
      "term" : {
         "product_type" : "A"
      }
   },
   "facets" : {
      "product_type" : {
         "global" : 1,
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "product_type"
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# [Wed Jan 18 17:15:09 2012] Response:
# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "product_type" : "A",
#                "product_name" : "foo bar"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.19178301,
#             "_index" : "my_index",
#             "_id" : "1",
#             "_type" : "product"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 0.19178301,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "facets" : {
#       "product_type" : {
#          "other" : 0,
#          "terms" : [
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "C"
#             },
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "B"
#             },
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "A"
#             }
#          ],
#          "missing" : 0,
#          "_type" : "terms",
#          "total" : 3
#       }
#    },
#    "took" : 4
# }
```

**UPDATE TO ANSWER THE EXPANDED QUESTION FROM THE OP:**

You can also apply filters directly to each facet - these are called `facet_filters`.

Similar example to before:

1) Create the index:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "product" : {
         "properties" : {
            "color" : {
               "index" : "not_analyzed",
               "type" : "string"
            },
            "name" : {
               "type" : "string"
            },
            "type" : {
               "index" : "not_analyzed",
               "type" : "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

2) Index some data:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/1?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "color" : "red",
   "name" : "foo bar",
   "type" : "A"
}
'

curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/2?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "color" : [
      "red",
      "blue"
   ],
   "name" : "foo bar",
   "type" : "B"
}
'

curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/3?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "color" : [
      "green",
      "blue"
   ],
   "name" : "bar",
   "type" : "C"
}
'
```

3) Search, filtering on products that have both `type`==`A`and `color` == `blue`, then run facets on each attribute excluding, the "other" filter:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/product/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "filter" : {
      "and" : [
         {
            "term" : {
               "color" : "blue"
            }
         },
         {
            "term" : {
               "type" : "A"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "facets" : {
      "color" : {
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "color"
         },
         "facet_filter" : {
            "term" : {
               "type" : "A"
            }
         }
      },
      "type" : {
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "type"
         },
         "facet_filter" : {
            "term" : {
               "color" : "blue"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# [Wed Jan 18 19:58:25 2012] Response:
# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [],
#       "max_score" : null,
#       "total" : 0
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "facets" : {
#       "color" : {
#          "other" : 0,
#          "terms" : [
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "red"
#             }
#          ],
#          "missing" : 0,
#          "_type" : "terms",
#          "total" : 1
#       },
#       "type" : {
#          "other" : 0,
#          "terms" : [
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "C"
#             },
#             {
#                "count" : 1,
#                "term" : "B"
#             }
#          ],
#          "missing" : 0,
#          "_type" : "terms",
#          "total" : 2
#       }
#    },
#    "took" : 3
# }
```

Comment: Thanks. In this simple case that works. How about if I have 2 properties, e.g:  `productcategory` and `color`. I'd like to facet on both properties and exclude any filter set on the property I'm filtering on. So faceting on `productcategory` excludes any `productcategory` filters while faceting on `color` excludes any `color` filters. Making facets global doesn't work in this case (I believe), since I want faceting on `productcategory` to take any possible `color`-filters in account and vice versa. I realize this is a different question btw.

Comment: I've expanded the answer above, to demonstrate how to do it

Comment: Good to know the existence of facet_filters. Do I understand correctly that specifying `facet_filters` on a facet overrides the (global) filters set? I would have thought that I needed to set `global: 1` on the facet as well to dictate the facet to ignore the globally set filters.

Comment: The scope of the facet can either be documents matched by "main" query or "global" (ie all documents in the index(es)/type(s).  `facet`_filters` affect just that facet, whatever scope it is using.

Comment: Btw, you can read more about facets here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/

Comment: Is there are a better solution for this kind of problem in the latest elasticsearch version? Maybe something can be done with aggregations? Or there are the same story with `filter aggregations` (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)?